# how to restore Nuget package for .net6 for Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data 2.0.0?

Tags: c#, warnings, .net-6.0, nuget-package

I am getting warning while using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data 2.0.0 on dot net 6 application.

warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data 2.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

what is the nuget package for .net6 ?

As of now I have tries supressing the warning via

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data" Version="2.0.0">
      <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
  </PackageReference>
```

but not sure that is the correct way or not.

I could not find supported package for .net6.

Please advise

Comment: There is no version of this package compatible with .NET 6, or any modern .NET (non-Framework). This package was made in 2014, when there wasn't even .NET Core 1.0. You should find a different package to do what you want.

Comment: What do you need this package for?

Comment: Thanks @Orion

The purpose of using the "Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data" package was to use SqlHelper class.

Solution: **Create our own implementation of SqlHelper** class and remove the package "Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data" from our application.